# Laravel mail sending error $address must be public

Tags: laravel, email

Laravel Framework 10.13.1
I generate a mail file and its markup according to the documentation

```
php artisan make:mail TokenVerification --markdown=emails.token
```

call

```
   Mail::to('admin@example.com')->send(new TokenVerification());
```

error

```
{
    "message": "Access level to Symfony\\Component\\Mime\\Address::$address must be public (as in class Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailables\\Address)",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError",
    "file": "/var/www/ipala-udev/vendor/symfony/mime/Address.php",
    "line": 25,
    "trace": []
}
```

This is the mail code of what laravel generates `TokenVerification.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TokenVerification extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     */
    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: 'Token Verification',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     */
    public function content(): Content
    {
        return new Content(
            markdown: 'emails.token',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the attachments for the message.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment>
     */
    public function attachments(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

I suppose that the problems are in the `Envelope` object, that has the address field, but it’s not clear how to fix it. Any ideas how to find where the error is coming from?

Error and StackTrace

```
Access level to Symfony\Component\Mime\Address::$address must be public (as in class Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Address)


namespace Symfony\Component\Mime;


use Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator;

use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\MessageIDValidation;

use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\RFCValidation;

use Symfony\Component\Mime\Encoder\IdnAddressEncoder;

use Symfony\Component\Mime\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;

use Symfony\Component\Mime\Exception\LogicException;

use Symfony\Component\Mime\Exception\RfcComplianceException;


/**

 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>

 */

final class Address extends \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Address

{

    /**

     * A regex that matches a structure like 'Name <email@address.com>'.

     * It matches anything between the first < and last > as email address.

     * This allows to use a single string to construct an Address, which can be convenient to use in

     * config, and allows to have more readable config.

     * This does not try to cover all edge cases for address.

     */

    private const FROM_STRING_PATTERN = '~(?<displayName>[^<]*)<(?<addrSpec>.*)>[^>]*~';


    private static EmailValidator $validator;

    private static IdnAddressEncoder $encoder;


    private string $address;
```

open file `/vendor/symfony/mime/Address.php ide phpstorm immediately tells me what to change to public and the error is changing

```
{
    "message": "Type of Symfony\\Component\\Mime\\Address::$address must not be defined (as in class Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailables\\Address)",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError",
    "file": "/var/www/ipala-udev/vendor/symfony/mime/Address.php",
    "line": 25,
    "trace": []
}
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste the error **with its entire stacktrace** in your original question

Comment: @UnderDog I used api requests and there is a shortened version of the errors, in principle it is clear in the web stacktrace error. Updated the question, stacktrace at the very bottom

Comment: I asked a **very specific thing** and you show a piece of the framework. Good luck debugging that. You need to create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I would also check the from address.  use tinker to inspect config('mail') and check the from details are present and correct

Comment: @Snapey I don’t see any problems in setting `config('mail')`.  ` Global "From" Address` in /config/mail.php is present. I don't understand why the error states that the `Address` property is `private`, while it is `public` in the framework code.

Comment: @АлександрИнженер did you modify any file inside vendor folder ?  the class  Symfony\Component\Mime\Address should not be extending any other class.

Comment: @N69S Thanks for the help. No, I have not changed anything and never edit anything in the vendor directory. This is an almost clean project, there are few edits in it, and it is not clear where this error comes from

Comment: > I don't understand why the error states that the Address property is private, while it is public

No, it is private, but assuming nothing has been edited then thats correct.  `private string $address;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never modify the vendor files as any modification in them will be overwritten when updating the packages or making a new installation without the proper lock.

I suggest you delete the `vendor` folder and run the command `composer install` to make a new one.

Keep in mind that this will delete any changes you made in the vendor folder but that will fix your issue and many hidden other ones.

Comment: I have never changed anything in the directory vendor, it does not make sense, after the updates everything will be overwritten. Created a new project and there really is no inheritance for the Address class. I have only one option, this is IDE `php-storm` added inheritance for some reason, I have no other options. Thank you.

Comment: Php storm and any intellij IDEs do not modify the code without the user prompt to do so.

Comment: Perhaps I was inattentive, but unfortunately all php code editors are sad, especially those that change the code in the vendor directory

Comment: actually when you try to modify a vender file, phpstorm shows a popup asking you to confirm what you are doing ^^ it knows

Comment: I didn't force open the vendor directory until the error occurred, and only then did I try to change the property from private to public. I have only one option, this is when importing some kind of class dependency, the editor changed the inheritance. I was very surprised because in all editors, the source classes are always in read mode, but not in phpstorm